# Is there a way to calculate the difference between a user's input and a specific number?

Tags: input, printing

For example:

number = input("Enter a nice number:")
nice_num = 69

if number == str(nice_num):
    print("Nice")

if number != str(nice_num):
    print("Piss off, you dummy")

I want to add that after print("Piss off, you dummy")

Comment: Do you mean using absolute to find the difference. If the number is higher or lower won't matter. abs(x-y) or just convert to int and subtract?

Comment: Nvm i'm just dumb